# Twitter: How can I form a set of related hashtags?

Tags: twitter, twitter-client

Now that I know I can no longer communicate with Twitter mashups out there, how can I create a set of related hashtags? For instance, how can I get all tags similar or related to yankees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the mathematical equations for [clustering related things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

Another, naive option, would be to just look at what hashtags frequently (subjective, I know) appear with a known hashtag and work from there.

Comment: Thanks so regarding your first suggestion, I would actually put that as my last option (only because I need to collect huge amounts of real-time data before I can do some analysis that is actually worth it and the measurement infrastructure should stay in place no matter what). As for the second approach, a small question I had was: If I search for #computer, twitter gives me only those posts with #computer. Am I right or did you ever happen to see other "related" tags as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a term extractor on set of tweets returned by the topic of your choice. Eg: Get the list of tweets for search query 'yankees' and apply term extractor on the set of tweets you have. You can find Term Extraction APIs from Yahoo! and AlchemyAPI.

The result would set of important terms used in the tweets and you can use them with a hash to search for more related information.